I have a question about setState in React, specifically when it's inside a callback function of a fetch and when it's not
why in the first code when the setAllMemes is called the component wait for all the code to finish before re-rendering and in the second code it re-render before the code has finished
first code
import React from "react"

export default function Meme() {
    console.log("react render")
    const [allMemes, setAllMemes] = React.useState([])

    console.log("allMemes outside the use effect" , allMemes)    

    React.useEffect(() => {
    
        console.log("before setAllMemes")
        setAllMemes(["string1","string2"]);
        console.log("after setAllMemes");
            
        console.log("allMemes inside the use effect" , allMemes);
    }, [])

    return (
        <main>
        
        </main>
    )
}

the output in the console
›react render
›allMemes outside the use effect,[]
›before setAllMemes
›after setAllMemes
›allMemes inside the use effect,[]
›react render
›allMemes outside the use effect,["string1", "string2"]

second code
import React from "react"

export default function Meme() {
     console.log("react render")
     const [allMemes, setAllMemes] = React.useState([])

     console.log("allMemes outside the use effect" , allMemes)    

     React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("before setAllMemes")
                setAllMemes(data.data.memes);
                console.log("after setAllMemes");
                })
        console.log("allMemes inside the use effect" , allMemes);
        }, [])

        return (
            <main>
        
            </main>
        )
    }

the output in the console
›react render
›allMemes outside the use effect,[]
›allMemes inside the use effect,[]
›before setAllMemes
›react render
›allMemes outside the use effect [array of object from the api]
›after setAllMemes


Something is off with your output. Check by running this snippet. It is not rendering before after setAllMemes.


function Meme() {
     console.log("react render")
     const [allMemes, setAllMemes] = React.useState([])

     console.log("allMemes outside the use effect" , allMemes)    

     React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("before setAllMemes")
                setAllMemes(data.data.memes);
                console.log("after setAllMemes");
                })
        console.log("allMemes inside the use effect" , allMemes);
        }, [])

        return (
            <main>
        
            </main>
        )
    }
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Meme />);
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




Thank you, I was using the scrimba.com IDE, and the output it was showing was wrong.

In the first code snippet, the setAllMemes function is called synchronously inside the useEffect hook. Since this is synchronous, it completes before the next lines of code execute. When you log allMemes inside the useEffect, it still shows an empty array because the state update hasn't taken effect yet. When the component re-renders after the state update, the updated allMemes array is displayed.
In the second code snippet, the setAllMemes function is called asynchronously inside the useEffect hook after fetching data from an api. The fetch returns a Promise, and the setAllMemes function is called in the Promise's then callback. This means that setAllMemes is called asynchronously, and the next lines of code after the fetch operation continue to execute while the data is being fetched. When you log allMemes inside the useEffect, it still shows an empty array because the state update hasn't happened yet.

i know that but i want to know why in the second code when the setAllMemes is called asynchronously why it re-render the component and don't wait for the console.log("after setAllMemes") to finish

the component re-renders immediately after the fetch operation is initiated, before the state update is completed, which is why you see the initial render with an empty array and then the updated render with the fetched data after setAllMemes is called.

i know that, but that is not my question, my question is why in the first code the execution is
console.log("before setAllMemes");
setAllMemes(data.data.memes);
console.log("after setAllMemes");
console.log("allMemes inside the use effect" , allMemes);
and then re-render
and in the second code the excution is
console.log("before setAllMemes");
setAllMemes(data.data.memes);
then re-render
then console.log("after setAllMemes");
why it the second code setAllMemes doesn't wait for the code to finish and re-render the componenet directly
